# Не получается определить тип: expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript

```
type pictureType = {
  portrait: string,
  landscape: string
}

const picture: pictureType = {
  portrait: require('./img/nc_ss19_620x960px_1.png'),
  landscape: require('./img/960x576_1.png')
};
```

```
const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState('');
setOrientation('portrait') // Например
...
<Image source={picture[orientation]} />
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'pictureType'.

Как мне правильно описать тип? Пробовал разные способы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите чтоб возвращаемое значение `useState` было ключом типа `pictureType`, то это можно сделать так:

```
const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState<keyof pictureType>('');
```